# Adding image using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a html page in which there is an image in anchor tag code is :

```
<a href="www.google.com" id="x"><img src="images/test.png" /></a>
```

on body onload event i am calling a javascript function which dynamically changes the image . My code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeImage()
{
  document.getElementById('x').innerHTML= '<img src="images/test2.png" />'; 
}
</script>
```

This is working fine in firefox but not working in google chrome and ie. Please help..

Comment: Is the missing opening `<` to the `img` tag a typo or your actual code looks like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
<a href="www.google.com" id="x"><img id="y" src="images/test.png" /></a>
```

in js

```
function changingImg(){
    document.getElementById("y").src="./images/test2.png"
}
```

---

Tested in Chrome and IE.

---

Then try this: [hoping that id of `<a>` is available and have at least one img tag]

```
var x = document.getElementById("x");
var imgs = x.getElementsByTagName("img");
imgs[0].src="./images/img02.jpg";
```

Comment: i cant't give id to image tag bcoz it is generating image dynamically . i am using joomla .

Answer (score 4):

try following instead of changing innerHTML.

```
function changeImage()
{
  var parent = documeent.getElementById('x');
  parent.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src = "newUrl";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have indicated, there are many ways to do this. The A element isn't an anchor, it's a link. And no one really uses XHTML on the web so get rid of the XML-style syntax.

If you don't have an id for the image, then consider:

```
function changeImage(id, src) {

  var image;
  var el = document.getElementById(id);

  if (el) {
    image = el.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];

    if (image) {
      image.src = src;
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can use an onload listener:

```
<body onload="changeImage('x', 'images/test.png');" ...>
```

or add a script element after the link (say just before the closing body tag) or use some other strategy for running the function *after* the image is in the document.