# How to add images to my questionnaire using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've tried everything that I could think of when trying to add an image into my quiz. I'm pretty new to HTML coding, and I'm at a loss. I'm trying to get it so that the when the web page is opened, an image is displayed above the question.

```
var myQuestions = [
    {
        question: "1. What are the warning signs of a phishing email?",
        answers: {
            A: 'Spelling errors',
            B:'Unfamiliar links',
            C: 'Asking for personal details',
            D: 'A, B and C'
        },
        correctAnswer: 'D'
    },
];
```

I'm unsure where to put the code that is needed to generate the image with the quiz.

```
var quizContainer = document.getElementById('quiz');
var resultsContainer = document.getElementById('results');
var submitButton = document.getElementById('submit');

generateQuiz(myQuestions, quizContainer, resultsContainer, submitButton);

function generateQuiz(questions, quizContainer, resultsContainer, submitButton) {

    function showQuestions(questions, quizContainer) {
        var output = [];
        var answers;
        for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
            answers = [];
            for(letter in questions[i].answers) {
                answers.push(
                    '<label>'
                        + '<input type="radio" name="question'+i+'" value="'+letter+'">'
                        + letter + ': '
                        + questions[i].answers[letter]
                    + '</label>'
                );
            }
            output.push(
                '<div class="question">' + questions[i].question + '</div>'
                + '<div class="answers">' + answers.join('') + '</div>'
            );
        }
        quizContainer.innerHTML = output.join('');
    }
}
```

Here is what I have got to show for results, just in the case it is needed.

```
function showResults(questions, quizContainer, resultsContainer) {
    var answerContainers = quizContainer.querySelectorAll('.answers');
    var userAnswer = '';
    var numCorrect = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {

        userAnswer = (answerContainers[i].querySelector('input[name=question'+i+']:checked')||{}).value;

        if(userAnswer===questions[i].correctAnswer) {
            numCorrect++;
            answerContainers[i].style.color = 'lightgreen';
        }
        else {
            answerContainers[i].style.color = 'red';
        }
    }
    resultsContainer.innerHTML = numCorrect + ' out of ' + questions.length;
}

showQuestions(questions, quizContainer);
submitButton.onclick = function() {
    showResults(questions, quizContainer, resultsContainer);
}
```

Comment: Check this.Hope this will work for you.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5865841/9599873 ----------

Answer (score 1):

```
var img = document.createElement("img");

img.src = "image.png";
var src = document.getElementById("x");

src.appendChild(img);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am telling that if you want to add image above every question then use this code above every question tag you used.

```
<img src="source" border="n" align="top/bottom/left/right" width="n/n%" height="n/n%" >
```

Comment: The `align` attribute is obsolete. I think `border` is, too.