# Replace alert function with an image

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(".site-main").on("sf:ajaxstart",function(){
        alert("show loader");
    });
    $(".site-main").on("sf:ajaxfinish",function(){
        alert("hide loader");
    });
```

I got this above code from a forum and it is showing me the alerts as it should. However, I'm planning to show a loader image with location path `<img src="/path/image.gif" class="loader">` instead of the alert.

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 2):

You could do like this

```
        $(".site-main").on("sf:ajaxstart",function(){
            $('img.loader').show()
        });
        $(".site-main").on("sf:ajaxfinish",function(){
           $('img.loader').hide()
        });
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm no JS expert. I don't know where to put the image path. What is `img.loader`?

Comment: `img.loader` is the same thing as an `img` tag with a class attribute of `loader`.

Comment: Okay. Where do I put the image path? I'm sorry. I'm just not a JS developer.

Comment: add the image in markup body https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_images_girl .Follow the website https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp  you know basic of js and web languages

Answer (score 0):

Note:- You can do [toggle](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/)  [show](https://api.jquery.com/show/) [hide](https://api.jquery.com/hide/).based on events triggered. Here is the basic demo which will help you to understand the functionality.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    $("img").show();
  }).ajaxStop(function() {
    $("img").hide('slow');
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://icon-library.net/images/loading-icon-png/loading-icon-png-12.jpg" height='50px' width='50px' alt="Loading" class='loader' style="display:none">
<form>
  <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="showLoader(); return false;">Show Data</button>
</form>
<script>
  function showLoader() {
    $.post("/echo/json", {});
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't edit the HTML and so can't put the `<img>`. It has to be in the JS file itself.

Comment: @ElaineByene Okay Thanks for correcting me, answer updated. I think this will help you :-)

Comment: That would still require me to edit the HTML as I have to add `https://icon-library.net/images/loading-icon-png/loading-icon-png-12.jpg`. Is there no possibility to add image using JS with a class?

Comment: @ElaineByene, Yes you can do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865790/adding-image-using-javascript...but proper way to do this functionality is according to my answer. :-)